# Delayed chained payment to secondary user Paypal

Tags: php, paypal

I am using paypal method Delayed chained payment.

I want to send a payment to secondary paypal user after specific time like 60 days but in below code it is sending payment to secondary user immediatially or after any time.

```html
$result = $paypal->call(
  array(
    'actionType'  => 'PAY_PRIMARY',
    'currencyCode'  => 'USD',
    'feesPayer'  => 'EACHRECEIVER',
    
    'cancelUrl' => BX_DOL_URL_ROOT. 'adaptivePayments/cancel.php',
    'returnUrl' => BX_DOL_URL_ROOT. 'adaptivePayments/success.php',

    'receiverList' => array(
      'receiver' => array(
        array(
          'amount'  => '7',
          'email'  => 'john.clarke852-developer@gmail.com',
          'primary'=>'true',
        ),
        array(
          'amount'  => '2',
          'email'  => 'harish-facilitator@revinfotech.com',
          'primary'=>'false',
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ), 'Pay'
);
```